# any ideas why this may be closing the programme?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
 int number;
        cout<<" Please select which item to change:"<<endl;

        for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
        {
            cout<<i<<"   "<<v[i]->getName()<<endl;
        }


        cin>>i;
        cout<<"Current number of items:  "<<v[i]->getNumber()<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter new value: "<<endl;
        cin>>number;
```

This is within a switch case, but the programme is currently terminating after the for loop.
any ideas?

Comment: `i <= count` looks suspcious. If `count` is the number of elements in `v` it will access one too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
```

Should really use:

```
 for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
```

if there are `count` elements. When you try to access `v[ count ]` you are trying to move one past the end of the collection -- a classic off-by-one error -- and invoking UB.

Comment: Having changed this the programme now runs until after the selection where again it closes the programme

Comment: It is possibly the same problem. Once out of the loop, you need to pass `num - 1` if you want to access the `num`th element. In C, C++ all collections are indexed from `0`, `1`, ... `n-1` for a `n` element collection. So, to get the 4th element, you should use `v[ 3 ]->getNumber()`.